# ①異なる時間足（1時間と5分）のボリンジャーバンド同時表示　②1時間足のBB半分より上下で色を変える　①②を同時に表示する方法を教えてください。

Tags: pine-script

トレーディングビューに関する質問です。

①異なる時間足（1時間と5分）のボリンジャーバンド同時表示

②1時間足のBB半分より上下で色を変える　①②を同時に表示する方法を教えてください。
1時間足のみ基準線より上と下で色を塗りつぶしたいです。
上は青色。下は赤色

スクリプトを教えてください。

Comment: これ https://jp.tradingview.com/ のことだと思われますが、`Python`ではなく専用の`Pine`というスクリプトのようですね。[超初心者が「Pineスクリプト」をコピペして「TradingView」でストラテジーを動かす方法](https://number-x-value.com/1620.html), [Pythonでできると思ったらトレーディングビューはPineだった](https://note.com/2riun/n/n3483cb7deb3d) 頑張ってPythonで何かしている人もいるようですが。[Pythonを使って詳細なバックテストエンジンを作成](https://jp.tradingview.com/chart/USDJPY/Mr93xWs8/) あとこちらとか。[tradingview-ta 3.2.2 - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tradingview-ta/) 何か出来るようになるまでのハードルは高いと思われますが、頑張ってください。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちら、質問者さんがお試しになったソースコードはありますでしょうか。動かなくても構いません。単に条件が書いてあるだけで試行錯誤の様子が見られない質問文だと、どのくらいのレベルで回答すれば良いのか分からなかったり、そもそもイチから回答を作る労力が大きかったりして、なかなか回答が集まらない傾向にあります。質問文を [edit] してコードを追加いただけないでしょうか。